# Can I pass the templateUrl to the directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to pass a `templateUrl` to my directive. I understand I can use transclusion, but that seems too much.  For example, I have a `widget` directive that I want to fill with specific html.  Is there a way to pass it in like:

```
<div widget templateUrl="template1.html"></div>
<div widget templateUrl="template2.html"></div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If this is a fixed URL you can define a directive such as

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return tAttrs.templateUrl;
        }
    };
});
```

then use it like this

```
<div my-directive template-url="template1.html"></div>
```

Otherwise you could pass the URL as you would pass any other attribute into a directive and use `ng-include` in your directive's template.

Comment: You cannot use function as `templateUrl` in Angular 1.0.8 so be sure to use at least Angular 1.1.4.

Comment: Good point. It's been a while since I've used stable branch! `ng-include` should still work though either way.

Comment: Is it posible that passing variable to template-url instead template1.html? @Andyrooger

Comment: @ddagsan If you're talking about using template-url like an `'='` bound scope member, then I don't think it's possible. You'd need access to a scope, but I think the template function will run before that's available. This answer is quite old now though, so there may be a better way to deal with this whole problem now in newer versions of angular.

Comment: I was looking for how to do this with a component vs. a directive, but your answer got me closer to my answer, $element & $attrs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33846452/3507333