# templateUrl function is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to create a custom angular component that dynamically loads a template based on a templateUrl function. I currently get a `templateUrl` is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode' error. Normally I understand that this error crops up when an injected service doesn't get properly annotated (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi). However, I am missing how this applies to `templateUrl`.

I'm using Angular 1.5.

Exact error message is -
`angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:strictdi] templateUrl is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`

Component Code snippet:

```
angular.module('hive.triGrid')
.controller('TriGridCellController', ['$element', '$attrs', function     ($element, $attrs) {
    var $ctrl = this;
}]) 
.component('triGridCell', {
controller: 'TriGridCellController',
templateUrl: function($element, $attrs)
{
    var type = $attrs.cellType;
    if(type.toUpperCase() == "ICON")
    {
        return "components/grid/cellTemplates/iconCell.tpl.html";
    }
    else if(type.toUpperCase() == "CUSTOM")
    {
        return $attrs.cellTemplateUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        return "components/grid/cellTemplates/textCell.tpl.html"; 
    }
},
//template:"<ng-include src='$ctrl.getTemplateUrl(z)'/>",
bindings: {
    cellData:'<',
    cellType: '<', //See triGridRow and triGrid for config JSON format.
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Code after answer was applied:

```
templateUrl: ['$element', '$attrs', function($element, $attrs)
{
    var type = $attrs.cellType;
    if(type.toUpperCase() == "ICON")
    {
        return "components/grid/cellTemplates/iconCell.tpl.html";
    }
    else if(type.toUpperCase() == "CUSTOM")
    {
        return $attrs.cellTemplateUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        return "components/grid/cellTemplates/textCell.tpl.html"; 
    }
}],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841909/angular-1-5-component-method-templateurl-function), `$element` and `$attrs` are injected into `templateUrl` function, not just passed as arguments. This is the difference between `element` parameter name (in `link` or `compile` functions) and `$element` local dependency in DI-enabled functions that Angular documentation emphasizes.

`templateUrl` function is [invoked by injector](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.0-beta.2/src/loader.js#L366-L368) in components, so any other services can be injected there as well, and it should be properly annotated.

Comment: For some reason I didn't think to apply that to the component setup functions. That worked for me.

Comment: This is a substitute for directive factory function, so services could be injected in every place in component where they are needed.

Comment: One issue I'm still facing is that the $attrs.cellType returns the raw text from my template, not the actual controller value that should be getting passed in. I'm attempting to resolve a template based on configuration, rather than predetermined text. In this case do I need to start dabbling into compiling and linking as well as using a raw directive?

Comment: That's correct. As noted in the linked answer, `templateUrl` cannot be used to obtain interpolated attributes, because the function is executed before directive `compile` and long before the first digest. Components are supposed to be straightforward self-contained widgets, and what you're trying to do is similar to ng-include directive, which is hacky and complex enough. If it is possible to make $attrs.cellType static and use its raw value, this will save you a lot of troubles.

Comment: Not possible to use static values, but I can turn it into a directive instead of a component.