# Pass querystring parameter for component in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

How to pass query string parameter for component in angular

```
app.component('test', {
     templateUrl: '/_directive/test.tpl.html',
     bindings: {
     currenttab: "="
     },
     controllerAs: 'test',
     controller: test  });
```

I want to like this:

```
 templateUrl: '/_directive/test.tpl.html?version=' + version;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the url as `"/_directive/test.tpl.html" + version`, becuse that will compile to `/_directive/test.tpl.html0.0.1` and this `html` is not found, so we should change it to `"/_directive/test.tpl.html?" + version` or `"/_directive/test.tpl.html?version=" + version` to have better result:

```
/_directive/test.tpl.html?0.0.1
/_directive/test.tpl.html?version=0.0.1
```

for sending public params in all the project we have to set theme before define angular app, see the example

```
window.version = "0.0.1";

var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.component('test', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/home-template.html?' + window.version,
    controller: function() {
        console.log(window.version)
    }
});
```

check your **Network** tab in the *chrome* or *firefox* to see the compile mode.

Comment: Your answer is right, but  **templateUrl** not access direct value. So i  have use **template** field and use ng-transclude & fire on change event on controller

Comment: Right answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841909/angular-1-5-component-method-templateurl-function?noredirect=1&lq=1