# Can a component definition use method of a components controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

still learning angularJS and was thinking about dynamic loading of templates or template urls like "template: vm.getTemplate()"

I tried to find out how I can use a controllers function in the components definition.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('trax')
        .component('contentLoader', {
            template: vm.getTemplate(),
            bindings: {
            },
            controller: ContentLoaderController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });

    function ContentLoaderController(){

        var vm = this;

        vm.getTemplate = function getTemplate(){
            return '<div>Example Template</div>'
        }

    }

})();
```

Regards, n00n

Comment: In your example getTemplate is static. What exactly is it supposed to do in your case? It's impossible to use controller method there because controller instance doesn't exist at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 1.5 component method templateUrl + function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841909/angular-1-5-component-method-templateurl-function)

Comment: @estus I try to get a dynamic template. ContentLoader component, returns an template due to the given route.

Comment: Since this is not possible, I'd suggest to re-ask the question considering your real case. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows how routing and ContentLoader are supposed to work.